# Quadruple nested child elements in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to create dummy data with FactoryGirl.

User has many posts, post has many videos, video has many comments.
Comment belong to video and user.
Video belongs to post and user.
Post belongs to user.

I would like to create at least 20 users, each with at least 10 posts, each post with at least 1 video, each video with at least 1 comment.

Thus far I have the following factories however I can't seem to get the videos or comments to work.

## spec/factories/comments.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    sequence(:body) { |n| "#{n}body" }
    video
    user
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/posts.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "#{n}title" }
    date Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    body Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3)
    tags Faker::Lorem.words(4)
    user

    trait :with_videos do
      after(:build) do |post|
        create(:video, post: post)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name  Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name  Faker::Name.last_name
    sequence(:username) { |n| "#{n}username" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{n}email@website.com" }
    phone  Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    password  Faker::Internet.password(6, 20)
    country  Faker::Address.country
    state  Faker::Address.state_abbr
    city  Faker::Address.city
    zip  Faker::Address.zip
    seeking_coach true
    accept_email true
    accept_phone true
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/videos.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :video do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "#{n}title" }
    sequence(:url) { |n| "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYm_#{n}2oCVdSM" }
    embed_id { "#{url}.split('=').last" }
    post
    user

    trait :with_comments do
      after(:build) do |video|
        create(:comment, video: video)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in factories hook should be `after(:create)` instead of `after(:build)`, e.g.:

```
after(:create) do |video|
  create(:comment, video: video)
end
```

Here is all updated factories:

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name  Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name  Faker::Name.last_name
    sequence(:username) { |n| "#{n}username" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{n}email@website.com" }
    phone Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    password Faker::Internet.password(6, 20)
    country Faker::Address.country
    state Faker::Address.state_abbr
    city Faker::Address.city
    zip Faker::Address.zip
    seeking_coach true
    accept_email true
    accept_phone true

    trait :with_10_posts do
      after(:create) do |user|
        create_list(:post, 10, :with_videos, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/posts.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "#{n}title" }
    date Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    body Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3)
    tags Faker::Lorem.words(4)
    user

    trait :with_videos do
      after(:create) do |post|
        create(:video, :with_comments, post: post)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/videos.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :video do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "#{n}title" }
    sequence(:url) { |n| "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYm_#{n}2oCVdSM" }
    post

    trait :with_comments do
      after(:create) do |video|
        create(:comment, video: video)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/comments.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    sequence(:body) { |n| "#{n}body" }
    video
  end
end
```

And RSpec test to ensure that factories setup works:

```
describe 'Factories' do
  it 'creates 20 users, each with at least 10 posts, each post with at least 1 video, each video with at least 1 comment' do
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 20, :with_10_posts)
    expect(User.count).to eq(20)
    user = User.take
    expect(user.posts.count).to be >= 10
    post = user.posts.take
    expect(post.videos.count).to be >= 1
    video = post.videos.take
    expect(video.comments.count).to be >= 1
  end
end
```

Here is all the code - https://github.com/shhavel/stackoverflow_question_40136020